# `NSDocument`'s `data(ofType:)` getting data from (async) `actor`

Tags: swift, concurrency, nsdocument

I've a document based macOS, that's using a `NSDocument` based subclass.

For writing the document's file I need to implement `data(ofType:) -> Data` which should return the document's data to be stored on disk. This is (of course) a synchronous function.

My data model is an `actor` with a function that returns a `Data` representation.

The problem is now that I need to `await` this function, but `data(ofType:)` wants the data synchronously.

How can I force-wait (block the main thread) until the actor has done its work and get the data?

EDIT:
In light of Sweepers remark that this might be an XY-problem I tried making the model a `@MainActor`, so the document can access the properties directly. This however doesn't allow me to create the model in the first place:

```
@MainActor class Model {}

class Document: NSDocument {
let model = Model() <- 'Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context'
}
```

I then tried to make the whole `Document` a `@MainActor`, but that makes my whole app to collapse in compiler errors. Even the simplest of calls need to be performed async. This doesn't allow any kind of upgrade path to the new concurrency system.

In the past my model was protected by a serial background queue and I could basically do `queue.sync {}` to get the needed data out safely (temporarily blocking the main queue).

I've looked into the `saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:` and I think I can use this very much to my need. It allows async messaging that saving is finished, so I now override this method and in an async `Task` fetch the data from the model and store it in temporarily. I then call super, which finally calls `data(forType:)` where I return the data.

Comment: I feel like this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This isn't something you would normally want to do...

Comment: Never heard of the XY problem :)

Comment: Anyway, I’m using an actor to allow concurrent access to the model.

Comment: Have you tried overriding a save method with a completion handler or delegate like `saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:`?

Comment: If you want to block the main thread, you can't do it with your custom `actor`. Only the `MainActor` runs on the main thread.

Comment: @Willeke Seems your comment leads to a workable solution, if you can make it some sort of answer I can mark it as such.

Comment: It was just an idea. Feel free to answer your own question if you have a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea by @Willeke in the comments, I came up with the following solution:

```
private var snapshot: Model.Snapshot?

override func save(to url: URL, ofType typeName: String, for saveOperation: NSDocument.SaveOperationType, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    //Get the data and continue later
    Task {
        snapshot = await model.getSnapshot()
        super.save(to: url, ofType: typeName, for: saveOperation, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
    defer { snapshot = nil }

    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        throw SomeError()
    }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try encoder.encode(snapshot)

    return data
}
```

As the `save()` function is prepared to handle the save result asynchronous we first take the snapshot of the data and then let the save function continue.